# Encode unique observations using identifier

Tags: r, dataframe, row, encode

I have a data frame where one column is consisting of strings, which is a unique identifier to a journey. A reproducible data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(tours = c("ansc123123", "ansc123123", "ansc123123", "baa3999", "baa3999", "baa3999"),
                 order = rep(c(1, 2, 3), 2))
```

Now my real data is much larger with many more observations and unique identifiers, but I would like to have an output on the format as when you do something like this (but not manually encoded), so that the journeys with the same `tours` value get encoded as the same journey.

```
df$journey <- c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert it to a `factor`.

```
df$journey <- as.integer(factor(df$tours))

df$journey
#[1] 1 1 1 2 2 2
```

Or use `match` and `unique`.

```
match(df$tours, unique(df$tours))
```

Its also possible to use `factor` and get the integer values with `unclass`. Here the `levels` are saved, what allows to come back to the original values.

```
df$journey <- unclass(factor(df$tours))

df$journey
#[1] 1 1 1 2 2 2
#attr(,"levels")
#[1] "ansc123123" "baa3999"   

levels(df$journey)[df$journey]
#[1] "ansc123123" "ansc123123" "ansc123123" "baa3999"    "baa3999"   
#[6] "baa3999"
```

Answer (score 0):

A `dplyr` approach could be to use `mutate` with `cur_group_id()` and the `.by` command:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(journey = cur_group_id(), .by = tours)
```

Or for older versions of `dplyr`:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(tours) %>%
  mutate(journey = group_indices())
```

Output:

```
#        tours order journey
# 1 ansc123123     1       1
# 2 ansc123123     2       1
# 3 ansc123123     3       1
# 4    baa3999     1       2
# 5    baa3999     2       2
# 6    baa3999     3       2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df)

df[, journey := .GRP, tours]
```

Answer (score 0):

With `dplyr 1.1.0` https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/group_data.html

We could use: `group_indices()` returns an integer vector the same length as .data that gives the group that each row belongs to.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(tours) %>% 
  group_indices()

[1] 1 1 1 2 2 2
```